# Sub-Consulta MYSQL (SELECT MIN)

Tags: sql

Eu tenho este codigo, mas o que eu quero é o `SELECT MIN` do "n_remadores" e só apenas o número min. Queria o clube com menos remadores. Ajudinha? :)

```
SELECT (clube.nome) AS clube,
       COUNT(remadores.cod_remador) AS n_remadores
FROM clube,
     remadores
WHERE clube.cod_clube=remadores.cod_clube
GROUP BY clube.nome
HAVING COUNT(remadores.cod_remador) >= ALL
  (SELECT COUNT(remadores.cod_remador) AS n_remadores
   FROM clube,
        remadores
   WHERE clube.cod_clube= remadores.cod_clube
   GROUP BY remadores.nome)
```

Comment: Qual o banco de dados ?: e o que exatamente vocÊ quer ? o min da sub query ? ou o apenas o numero min do resultado ?//

Comment: MySQL. Quero o min do resultado (n_remadores)

Comment: você fala uma linha com o nome do clube e o min de remadores.cod_remador ... ou você esta tentando pegar uma linha para cada clube com o valor min da sub query ?

Comment: SELECT (clube.nome) AS clube,
       COUNT(remadores.cod_remador) AS n_remadores
FROM clube,
     remadores
WHERE clube.cod_clube=remadores.cod_clube
GROUP BY clube.nome                                                                          //Quero o resultado mínimo desta consulta!

Comment: Qual bd a solução muda conforme o bd , top sqlserver, limit mysql , rownum oracle etc.

Comment: phpMyAdmin, MySql

Answer (score 0):

Use tabelas temporárias.

```
SELECT min(cod_remador) FROM
(SELECT (clube.nome) AS clube,
       COUNT(remadores.cod_remador) AS n_remadores
FROM clube,
     remadores
WHERE clube.cod_clube=remadores.cod_clube
GROUP BY clube.nome
HAVING COUNT(remadores.cod_remador) >= ALL
  (SELECT COUNT(remadores.cod_remador) AS n_remadores
    FROM clube,
        remadores
   WHERE clube.cod_clube= remadores.cod_clube
   GROUP BY remadores.nome)) AS Temp
```